# This.close() closing main form aswell

Tags: c#, winforms

been trying to figure this out for about an hour!

I made an app that has 1 main form which is launched in Program.cs like this

```
frmFleetMain frmW = new frmFleetMain();
frmW.iNIPathAndFile = GlobalInfo.iNIPathAndFile;
frmW.SetUser(GlobalInfo.Username);
Application.Run(frmW);
```

and 1 sub form that is launched in the main form like this

```
                if (recordid != "")
                {
                    frmFleetSave frmsave = new frmFleetSave();
                    frmsave.Rowid = int.Parse(recordid);
                    frmsave.ShowDialog();                        

                   dgvMain.Rows[rowindx].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;                       

               oFuel.Filter = FLEET_FUEL.ColumnNames.FUEL_SEQUENCE + " = "+recordid;
                    oFuel.FLEET_NO = int.Parse(GlobalInfo.FLEETNO);
                    oFuel.Filter = "";
                    GlobalInfo.FLEETNO = "";
                }
```

In the btnclose event of frmsave i have this code

```
if (GlobalInfo.FLEETNO == "")
{
   DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Record will not be updated!Click OK to try again or CANCEL to close.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
   if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
   {                    
      this.Close();//this closes both forms -this is not what i want
   }
}
else
{
   this.Close();//this closes frmsave only-this is what i want:)
}
```

I cant figure out why this is happening!Help :)

SOLVED :

```
 if (recordid != "")
                {
                    frmFleetSave frmsave = new frmFleetSave();
                    frmsave.Rowid = int.Parse(recordid);
                    frmsave.ShowDialog();

                    if (frmsave.ssave)//get a bool variable indicating we can save! :-P
                    {

                        oFuel.Filter = FLEET_FUEL.ColumnNames.FUEL_SEQUENCE + " = " + recordid;
                        oFuel.FLEET_NO = int.Parse(GlobalInfo.FLEETNO);
                        oFuel.Filter = "";
                        GlobalInfo.FLEETNO = "";
                    }
```

}

Comment: Are the values of `this` the same when both lines execute?

Comment: Answer StuperUser's question using breakpoints. Post the values here. Break on the initial If statement (GlobalInfo), the instantiation of 'result' and on the nested If, break on all 3 and look at the point 'this' changes, if it does.

Comment: Is there any code after `frmsave.ShowDialog()`?

Comment: @StuperUser and Daniel - yes the value of this is the same namely -  this {FleetMain001.frmFleetSave, Text: Verification}

Comment: @Reniuz - Yes there is code after frmsave.showdialog(),Il put it up now

Comment: Is there something written in the frmFleetSave_Closing event?

Comment: **before calling** `this.Close();` try setting DialogResult for frmFleetSave form by : `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` or `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;` and see if it works..

Comment: Doesnt work,tried both @CSharpVJ

Answer (score 1):

try to change `frmsave.ShowDialog();` to `frmsave.ShowDialog(this);`

and change other code to:

```
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(this, "Record will not be updated!Click OK to try again or CANCEL to close.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Close();
        }
```

this works fine on my pc...

Comment: then frmsave doesnt close at all

Comment: you need to set the cancel button from the dialog properties. there is a property called CancelButton select the cancel button and try again...

Comment: the result holds the value that the user selects, so either 'ok' or 'cancel'-  if its ok then my form closes itself but if click cancel then the form closes itself and the main form

Comment: well there is a better and different approach I suggest you to use. I will update the answer...

Comment: i wait for your answer, i actually think this is a bug in VS, working with that dialog result is messing it up somewhere.

Comment: the different approach is a bit long and needs lots of codes changes. but I will give you some tips. you need to do the dialogResult check from the main window it will be easier and better. you will be controlling the dialog and its controls from the main application window..

Comment: Is that all your code changes? I implemented but still the same results...:(

Comment: I've ran into similar problems and they usually turn out to be simple programming logic error. I'd suggest you to write it in a different approach...

Comment: Solved by storing a bool in the child form and retrieving that bool value in the main form! Updating code...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED :

```
 if (recordid != "")
                {
                    frmFleetSave frmsave = new frmFleetSave();
                    frmsave.Rowid = int.Parse(recordid);
                    frmsave.ShowDialog();

                    if (frmsave.ssave)//get a bool variable indicating we can save! :-P
                    {

                        oFuel.Filter = FLEET_FUEL.ColumnNames.FUEL_SEQUENCE + " = " + recordid;
                        oFuel.FLEET_NO = int.Parse(GlobalInfo.FLEETNO);
                        oFuel.Filter = "";
                        GlobalInfo.FLEETNO = "";
                    }
```

}